# Multiple BLE Connections using Linux

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

hey even I am looking to connect multiple devices(sensors) to my computer. My process is working for a single connection. It goes something like this

```
bluetooth_adr = sys.argv[1]
tool = pexpect.spawn('gatttool -b ' + bluetooth_adr + ' --interactive')
tool.expect('\[LE\]>')
print "Preparing to connect. You might need to press the side button..."
tool.sendline('connect')
# test for success of connect
tool.expect('\[CON\].*>')
tool.sendline('char-write-cmd 0x29 01')
tool.expect('\[LE\]>')
```

How do I modify this so that multiple sensors would connect??

Thank you

Comment: What kernel version are you using?  3.4 and earlier has a bug that won't allow multiple L2CAP connections (well, without confusing which data goes to what socket).  Also, what version of Bluez are you using?